# Free Issue Tracking System Recomandation

Tags: issue-tracking, ticket-system

I am looking for a free online Issue Tracking System that allows public users to add tickets ( so no sign up required ). I already looked on other topics regarding ITS on stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything close to what I am looking for.

Any recommendations?

Regards.

Comment: Probably because product recommendations are off topic here. There is a sister site for that though.

Comment: Can you tell me that site please :)